# Comparing primary Id of the same row in same table

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Can't find the same questions as mine I'm hoping you guys can help me.
I have this query for my SP what I need to do is check if the company Id is the same based on the parameter given by the user.

I have two parameters which are paramOrgA and paramOrgB which will be supplied by the user.
What I did was repeat the same query and set the returned value in two variables which is
orgAId and orgBId then use the IF statement to compare the value.

is there another way to accomplish this or should I say optimized way to do this?

Below is the query I wrote.

```
BEGIN
declare orgAId int;
declare orgBId int;
declare orgStatus bool;

    SET orgAId = (SELECT c.Id
        FROM Members as `m`
        INNER JOIN Company as `c`
        ON m.CompanyId = c.Id
        WHERE m.Id = paramOrgA);
        
    SET orgBId = (SELECT c.Id
        FROM Members as `m`
        INNER JOIN Company as `c`
        ON m.CompanyId = c.Id
        WHERE m.Id = paramOrgB);
    
        
        IF (orgAId = orgBId) THEN
            set orgStatus = true;
        ELSE
            set orgStatus = false;
        END IF;
select orgStatus as 'CompanyStatus';
END IF;
END
```

Comment: an SP starts with [CREATE PROCEDURE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-procedure.html), and after that the name of the SP, and the parameters (and types of the parameters).   Why did you not supply that info ?

Comment: @Luuk i apologized i thought i will just explained how the parameter was used and it will be understood.

Comment: When asking about a SP, simply supply the complete SP.  when asking about a query, supply the query.  Some times (more often than you think) you should also supply table definitions.   Sample date (input, and desired output) might be helpful too.   (In this case the story about the SP is not really relevant, but because your statement is between `BEGIN` and `END` someone might ask what is before the BEGIN....)  your question should have a [mre].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One query will do

```
SELECT count(distinct c.Id) > 1 as 'CompanyStatus'
FROM Members as `m`
INNER JOIN Company as `c` ON m.CompanyId = c.Id
WHERE m.Id IN (paramOrgA, paramOrgB)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot i learned something new today.

Comment: Just to add this wont work if one of the parameters inside where clause does not exist in the table.

Comment: It works exactly like you specified it in your question.

Comment: yeah it works im just saying it will not work if one of the parameter supplied does not exist in the table. Because im comparing if the two parameter supplied is the same id or not. This is good if im trying to eliminate duplicate ID's but with my original solution using this one will not solve my ID comparison.

Answer (score 0):

Even fewer keystrokes:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT CompanyId) > 1 as 'CompanyStatus'
    FROM Members
    WHERE Id IN (paramOrgA, paramOrgB)
```